# Does temp table with PK and identity creates clustered index internally in sql server. Or we have to create explicitly

Tags: sql-server

Does temp table with PK and identity creates clustered index internally in sql server. Or we have to create explicitly?

I was working on SP optimization, and came across one article which says that #Temp table with bulk data can have temp db out of memory issue. i reduced #Table size to only few required columns which stores only int columns. Now considering sort operation, for actual table has some benefit of PK and Clusterd Index. so i was curious does #table utilize the same capabilities of SQL.

Comment: What is your actual question here? Are you asking if an identity is by default a clustered index? If that is the question then NO. The primary key (which is sometimes an identity) will be indexed. And if there is no clustered index already on the table then the primary key index will be clustered.

Comment: i am clear about Clustered index with relation of PK. but not sure whether #table has same behavior.

Comment: The best way to answer this is with actual testing. Create a temp table with and without a PK and look at the execution plans. It will create a clustered index just like a persistent table.

Answer (score 1):

`IDENTITY` is purely a property of a column, like `NOT NULL`. It isn't `CLUSTERED`, nor is it a `PRIMARY KEY` unless you tell SQL Server so.

`CREATE TABLE T (ID int IDENTITY);` will not create an index on the column `ID`, nor will be be indexed.

The only way you would create a `CLUSTERED INDEX` on an `IDENTITY` column would be by using synnax for declare it as your `CLUSTERED PRIMARY KEY` in your create, altering your table to add the `IDENTITY` column as a `CLUSTERED PRIMARY KEY` or creating a `CLUSTERED INDEX` on the column (as your primary key and Clustered Index  don't have to be the same column).